# adding/setting a cookie vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I know how to add / set cookies in VB.Net , usually I check if it is null ( or Nothing in VB) if it is nothing I set a new cookie , if it is not then I set the value of the previous cookie.  My question is there any thing wrong , or any down side to just adding a cookie every time like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("Lat", dt(0)(1).ToString().Trim()))
```

I'm hoping that this will just override the previous Cookie("Lat") if it exists , and set a new one if it doesn't , if this works it will really make my code a lot shorter and make things easier.  I don't see why this wouldn't work - but every tutorial and example online normally checks if it exists first.

Comment: Use `Set` method instead of `Add`. Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add (`duplicate`) cookie into the collection then use `Add` method and want to update an existing cookie then call the `Cookies.Set` method. (Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set.aspx))